Picture in the title sequence of "It Takes a Killer"
The show has a teaser opening and then proceeds to a title sequence. In this sequence the camera pans across a photo of what appears to be a person opening another person's mouth.  Presumably this is a victim or suspect in some famous case, but I don't know which one.
Screen cap below...

Question: what is going on in this photo? Who is it and why is someone trying to open the person's mouth?

This is a photo of notorious serial killer Ted Bundy getting his teeth cast. Forensic investigators then matched this impression to bite marks found on one of his victims, which helped to convict him. Here's another picture from this crucial moment:

